# this.render backbone removes jquery nav pills class

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js

I have the following structure for my backbone view

a main chart view which is as following:

```
<div id="id-main-charts">
<div id="id-time-tab">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified nav-prima">
        <li><a href="#" type="Daily" class="agraphType" data-toggle="tab">Daily</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" type="Weekly" class="agraphType" data-toggle="tab">Weekly</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" type="Monthly" class="agraphType" data-toggle="tab">Monthly</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#" class="agraphType" type="Quarterly" data-toggle="tab">Quarterly</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" type="Yearly" class="agraphType" data-toggle="tab">Yearly</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>

<div class="col-lg-5" id="id-sales-pie">

</div>

<div class="col-lg-7" id="id-sales-line">

</div>
```

MainChartView:

```
    var $ = require('jquery'),
    Handlebars = require('handlebars'),
    Backbone = require('backbone'),
    mainchartTemplate = require('../../templates/dashboard/ChartsContainer.html'),
    pieChartView = require('../../views/dashboard/PieChartView'),
    lineChartView = require('../../views/dashboard/LineChartView'),
    moment = require('moment');

var MainChartView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#id-charts-stats'),

    initialize: function() {

        this.pie = new pieChartView();
        this.line = new lineChartView();
    },
    events: {
        'click a.agraphType': "changeGraphData"
    },

    changeGraphData: function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var type = $(ev.target).attr('type');
        sessionStorage.setItem("typeOfGraph", type);
        this.render();

    },

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(mainchartTemplate);
        this.line.setElement(this.$('#id-sales-line')).delegateEvents().render();
        this.pie.setElement(this.$('#id-sales-pie')).delegateEvents().render();

    }
});

module.exports = MainChartView;
```

When i click on the nav pills it re renders the view and my selected tab is no more selected.

I tried removing the `this.render`it works fine then. But i need the render to re load my other subviews.

Please help.

Comment: That happens because your replacing the entire DOM tree of the view in your render. The element that used to be selected is not there anymore after you render (it's been replaced by one that looks just like it). You'll either have to store the information about what was selected before you re-render and then apply the selection after rendering, or load your other subviews without re-rendering the main view.

Comment: Guyz lets discuss all backbone.js related questions here : chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84541/backbonejs-mvc lets build this chat room & get answers really quick from active developers